# Decoding pandas query on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

### I want to decode this pandas query on data frame.

```
 filter1 = df['customer_planning_group'] == 'G01'
 filter3 = df['calendar_yearweek'].between(201929,201939) 
 filter4 = df['SKU_Name'].isin(un_name)
 final_filter = filter1 & filter3 & filter4
 df[['calendar_yearmonth', 'calendar_yearweek','predictions', 'total_sales_volume']].where(final_filter).groupby('calendar_yearweek').sum()
```

so far what i have understood
 1. the code is trying to select rows from data frame using multiple filters
 2. and then select a few columns from that result
 3. and then group by that result based on a column "calendar_yearweek"
 4. and then calculate sum in respective group.
 
is my understanding correct? 
is this the right way of conditional select, group and perform aggregate sum on a dataframe?

Dataframe size is close to 1GB and it may increase upto 4GB in near future

### how did i end up at this code

The data actually belong to a table in mysql but it was taking very large time there to process the same thing with sql.

i moved to python thinking reading entire file in pandas and then processing will decrease time.


i want to now whether above thinking is correct or not?

Comment: I'm not sure pandas is likely to be faster than sql. Are you able to create indexes in sql? That might help. Also, `filter1` and `filter2` look identical to me...

Comment: tried but time didnt reduce. indexing might not help as the amount of data per query result can be in GB. yes. i corrected that.